# Text Format Macro for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert a list of names, each in a seperate cell, into a list with # before each name commas afterwards and combined into a single cell. What type of macro would I use for that. So:

```
Help 

Me 

Please 

Thank 

You
```

into (single cell):

```
#help, #me, #please, #thank, #you
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function convertNames(startRow as long,endRow as long,column as long) as string

dim result as string  

for c=startRow to endRow
 result=result & "#" & Cells(c,column) & ", "
next

result=left(result,len(result)-2)

convertNames=result

end function
```

You would call this function in the cell where you want to display the results as:

```
=convertNames(5,12,2)
```

substituting in the start row, end row, and column index that you need.

Comment: Thanks! It's displaying just #, #, #, rather than the value in column a and the #, . Probably user error, but would love your thoughts!

Comment: Did you put the VBA function in the same worksheet where you're calling it, or did you put it in its own module?  If it's in its own module (or in a different worksheet), you need to specify the worksheet by changing `Cells(c,column)` to `Sheets("nameOfWorksheet").Cells(c,column)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
Function ConvertNames(List As Range) As String
  Dim C As Range

  For Each C In List
    ConvertNames = ConvertNames & "#" & C.Value2 & ", "
  Next C

  ConvertNames = Left(ConvertNames, Len(ConvertNames) - 2)
End Function
```

It is inspired by sigil's answer, but this one works with a range, and allows Excel to manage the references to cells. Sigil's function should be [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195441.aspx) and would slow down large files.

You need to add a module to the project and put this function in the module. Then you can use it by typing `=ConvertNames(A1:A5)` on the cell that uses it.

Comment: Agreed on the volatile function issue.  This is a better solution, since it lets you pass in any range and so doesn't have the worksheet referencing issue that may be affecting you with my solution.  Thanks stenci.